# cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\blah\blah\templmatch.cpp:589: error: (-215:Assertion failed)

Tags: python, image-recognition

I wrote a script using an imagesearch script as an example and it runs well, all but one error.

```
File "C:/Users/me/Desktop/python/animalID/test.py", line 55, in imagesearcharea
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED) 
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\templmatch.cpp:589: error: (-215:Assertion failed) corrsize.height <= img.rows + templ.rows - 1 && corrsize.width <= img.cols + templ.cols - 1 in function 'cv::crossCorr'
```

here is the part of the code it's running I'll explain what it does

First the script is shown 50 animal pictures, either from 0-199 pool or from 200-399 pool. It'll recognize what images they are and store the file name to an array. Then from time to time the word "animal" will be shown on the screen, when it does, a screenshot is taken and then the script compares the screenshot to all the animal pictures from the list in the array.

If the list in the array is from 0-199 it runs great, but if it's from 200-399 it crashes everytime.

```
def animalscanner():

    global namenumber
    global im
    global animaltype
    global currentnumber
    global threshold

    pos = imagesearch_loop("animal.png", 1)
    global im
    im = region_grabber((383, 625, 1078, 698)) 
    im.save('zzzzzztestarea.png')
    currentnumber = 0 #testing
    animaltypechecker()

def animaltypechecker():

    global namenumber
    global im
    global animaltype
    global currentnumber
    global threshold

    pos = imagesearcharea("w" + str(animaltype[currentnumber]) + ".png", 0, 0, 602, 38, threshold, im)
    while (pos[0] == -1):
        if currentnumber == 50: 
            currentnumber = -1
            threshold -= .01
        currentnumber +=1
        pos = imagesearcharea("w" + str(animaltype[currentnumber]) + ".png", 0, 0, 602, 38, threshold, im)
```

I thought it might be a corrupt image file so I retook the images 200-399 (via screenshot using the same script as I did when I made the first 400 images) but it still didn't work.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, I hope this is enough information, if not let me know what else to provide.